# Are two integrals same in length but different bounds equal?

Tags: calculus, integration

The integrals below result in different answers. Is this because the bounds are different although they are the same length? The integral, $$\int_0^1x^2dx = \frac{1}{3},$$ and $$\int_\frac {-1}{3}^\frac{2}{3}x^2dx = \frac{1}{9}.$$

This is just a shift of the curve in x so how could the area under it be different?

Comment: Try to sketch a picture of the situation and see if it helps. The key thing is that $x^2$ "grows more" in the interval $[2/3, 1]$, than it does in the interval $[-1/3,0]$, hence the difference in areas.

Comment: It's not a shift. You are taking a different cut of the curve.

Comment: I see it now, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

The integral  $$\int_0^1x^2dx = \frac{1}{3}$$ represents the area under the curve , $y=x^2$   on  the interval $[0,1]$ while

$$\int_\frac {-1}{3}^\frac{2}{3}x^2dx = \frac{1}{9} $$ represent the area under the same curve on 
$[-1/3, 2/3]$

There is no reason why these two areas should be the same.
You have shifted the interval without shifting the function. If you wanted the same area you should have shifted the function as well.

Try $$\int_\frac {-1}{3}^\frac{2}{3} (x+1/3)^2dx $$

to see the result.

Comment: I see it now, thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Thank you for your attention.